# Android studio does not create files

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, include-path

I added a new fragment to my project in Android studio like the way I did it a couple of times before, but now it says that this file das not exist (and is read only). I cannot edit a thing in it but also do not know how to correctly close it, so I can't use the name, which I really want...
I cannot find the file anywhere within my project and it is also not listed in the project+path (Name/App/src/main/...) but in the entire windows location (E:/...).
And how can I create a permanent file, or better, why does it not work any more?

Comment: Did you try just to restart Android Studio?

Comment: twice already. And I have all permission from windows

Comment: It works now, but I have no idea why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a fault on your side. Are you sure you are in the right folder? This is the only explanation I could think of. So you creat the files but outside of your project's folder, so you cannnot edit them or anything else, but read them...

Bene

Comment: actually, that was exactly my fault -.- pretty embarrassing

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you have no LINT ERRORS.**

For checking it:

Go to the bottom right side of Android Studio. Tap on "Gradle Console" tab.
If you have some errors(red text) - remove them and try again.